# Angular Form Undefined In Controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

Have an angular form that I'm passing into my controller.

When I open browser to inspect form, it is undefined. I've tried changing the name of the form, and moving the form tag to enclose the entire body. Here is my form:

```
         <form layout-padding id="form-container" ng-controller="RegisterController as RgCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak name="projectForm">
          <div id="content-row-header">What is your email?</div>
          <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-focused">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input required type="email" name="email" ng-model="email"
                   minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.email.$error" role="alert">
              <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
              </div>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
          <div id="content-row-header">Set a password</div>
          <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-focused">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input required name="password" ng-model="password">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.password.$error">
              <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </form>
```

Here is my function call:

`<md-button id="orange-button" ui-sref="app.unauthenticated.purchase.agent" ng-click="doRegistration(projectForm)" flex>Create Account</md-button>`

and here is my controller:

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.auth.register')
    .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function RegisterController($scope, $auth, $log, $location,$rootScope,$state,app_auth,$stateParams) {
    // Data
    var vm = this;

    // Methods
    $scope.doRegistration = function (form) {
      console.log(form);
      app_auth.register(form.email.$viewValue,form.password.$viewValue,form.passwordConfirm.$viewValue);
    };


    // $scope.goHome = function () {
    /
/   $state.go('app.public');
    // };
  }
})();
```

right now when that console.log(form) runs, form is undefined

Comment: $state.go('app.public'); should be commented?

Comment: just posted an answer, pls can you add the snippet of `md-input-container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a **directive**.
The **directive scope** is **different** from the **controllers**. That's why you are not able to see the form reference.

GO to directive implementation and add:

```
scope: {
  projectForm: '=',
},
```

reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/form-based-directives-angularjs/

Answer (score 1):

If you have some conditional directive in the form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-if="someVariable">
```

Then `$scope.myForm` will be undefined in your controller.

Besides, you should use ng-submit.

Answer (score 0):

name attribute will bind form controller to $scope, so you have `name="projectForm"` in your controller you should be able 
to use `$scope.projectForm`

check jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/hurricanew/6tqywue6/

Answer (score -1):

Register Controller had to encompass the form definition and function that took in a form as argument